# Unwanted space on left side of div

Tags: html, css, nav, spacing

There is an unwanted gap between the left side of my div and the actual content inside of it (text, images).  I have margin and padding both set to 0px for the class.  The div is also right next to my nav bar, which may be somehow affecting the spacing.

```
body
{
    background-color: #f5f5f7;
    background-image: url("../img/powder.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: right bottom;
    font-family: 'Lora', serif;
    padding: 0px;

}

.main /* the extra space is occuring in this class */
{
    position: relative;
    left: 200px;
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    text-align: left;
    border-radius: 10px;  
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(207, 207, 207, 0.5);
}

nav ul 
{
    background: #efefef; 
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #d3c965 0%, #89822a 100%);  
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #d3c965 0%, #89822a 100%); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #d3c965 0%,#89822a 100%); 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #d3c965 0%, #89822a 100%);  
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    padding: 0px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;  
    list-style: none;
/*  display: inline-table;*/
    margin: 0px;
}


nav ul li:hover 
{
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #993300, #4C1A00); /*Standard syntax */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #993300, #4C1A00);/* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #993300, #4C1A00);/* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #993300, #4C1A00); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
}

nav ul li:hover a 
{
    color: #fff;
}

nav ul li a 
{
    display: block; 
    padding: 25px 40px;
    color: #4C4C4C; 
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

The live version of this is available at msu.edu/~bridsonc/henna

Comment: Have you tried looking at the page with something like Chrome's developer tools? In my  experience this is the easiest way to solve this kind of thing.

Comment: Try either setting your .main to position: absolute; or even better, float it left like the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the div float like the menu.

```
.main {
    float: left
    /* change left:200px to margin-left:20px */
```

Maybe you could than add a `padding-left` of `10px`

Answer (score 0):

change the position of the div from relative to fixed:

```
.main /* the extra space is occuring in this class */
{
    position: fixed;
```